# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the function $f(t) := \mbox{trace}(A^{-1}e^{-tB} A e^{-tB})$ to be monotone decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrices. For any $t \ge 0$, define $f(t) := \mbox{trace}(A^{-1}e^{-tB} A e^{-tB}) = \|A^{-1/2}e^{-tB}A^{1/2}\|_F^2$.

**Question.** What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $f$ to be monotone decreasing.

### A sufficient condition

If $A$ and $B$ commute, then $A$ and $e^{-tB}$ commute for any $t \ge 0$. Thus, $f(t)=\mbox{trace}(AA^{-1}e^{-2tB}) = \mbox{trace}(e^{-2tB})$, which is clearly monotone decreasing in $t$.

Comment: In my opinion the assumption $\|B\|<1$ is not essential.

Comment: Yes, it's there for anecdotic reasons, to ensure f vanishes at Infinity. Removed.

Comment: Ok. It's funny: to get small $f(t)$ you should prefer large values of $\|B\|.$ Thanks for fixing anyway. Have you tested  your problem on $2\times 2$ matrices ?

Comment: Ya, a thinko. What I meant is that anecdotally, $e^{-tB}$ should be replaced with $(I_n-B)^t$, and the condition $\|B\|_{op}<1$ is there to ensure $f$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: When answering "Ya, a thinko" which language are you using ?

Comment: Besides, more seriously, what is the need for dividing by $n$ in this issue ?

Comment: The $1/n$ is due to aecdotical reasons (statistics), but is really just a distraction here. Removed.

Comment: @JeanMarie A nearest-neighbor query returns "The language is most likely English!"

Comment: The $1/n$ is due to anecdotical reasons (statistics), but is really just a distraction here. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you'll find a simple necessary and sufficient condition.  You do have

$$ \dfrac{df(t)}{dt} = -\text{trace}\left(A^{-1} e^{-Bt} (BA + AB) e^{-Bt}\right) = -\text{trace}\left(A^{-1/2} e^{-Bt} (BA+AB) e^{-Bt} A^{-1/2}\right) $$

so a somewhat more general sufficient condition is that $BA + AB$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for nice input. Upvoted.